Is FFTW in armadillo thread safe when operating on a slice
Is the following example code thread safe when using armadillo with ARMA_USE_FFTW3? In the FFTW documentation it says that the planner is not thread safe and I was wondering if armadillo handles this internally?
#include <iostream>
#include <armadillo>
#include <mkl_service.h>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;
using namespace arma;

void threadFunction(const mat& dataSlice, int index, vector<float>& results)
{
    vec y = mean(dataSlice,1);
    cx_vec a = arma::fft(y);
    double amax = arma::max(arma::abs(a));
    results[index] = amax;
}

void main()
{
    int numSlices = 4;
    cube x(128, 10, numSlices, fill::randu);

    vector<thread> threads(numSlices);
    vector<float> results(numSlices);

    // Create and start threads
    for (int i = 0; i < numSlices; ++i) {
        int sliceIndex = i;
        threads[i] = thread(threadFunction, x.slice(sliceIndex), sliceIndex, ref(results));
    }

    // Wait for all threads to complete
    for (auto& th : threads) {
        th.join();
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < numSlices; i++) {
        cout << "peak[" << i << "] = " << results[i] << endl;
    }


This works without problems with Armadillo version 12.8.3
